# RabbitMq program is hanging while handling 100k messages. is this the right way to do it?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

The code is attached below. my system hangs. is this the right way to create those many channels? 
i wanted to compare the cpu usage of rabbitMQ and redis pub/sub for 100k messages and i am running the rabbitMQ server on windows.

```
var amqp = require("amqplib/callback_api");
var time = 0;
var limit = 100000;
amqp.connect("amqp://localhost",function(err,conn){
  if(err){
    console.log('Connection closed-----------error connect');
    return;
  }
  var timer = setInterval(() => {
    time+=1;
    if(time>=limit){
      clearInterval(timer);
    }

    conn.createChannel(function(err,ch){
      if(err){
        console.log('Connection closed-----------error createChannel');
        return;
      }
      var q = "queue_name"+time.toString();
      // console.log(q);
      var msg = "this is the message string!!!";
      ch.assertQueue(q,{durable: false});
      ch.sendToQueue(q,new Buffer(msg),{persistent: false});
      // console.log("time = "+time);
    });
  }, 10);
});
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more context, where is the rabbitmq server located (Windows/Linux-Unix/Other)? Did you do its configuration? Did you check if he has enough ressources (filehandles, ...)?

Comment: What do you want??? 100k simultaneous connections? Or 100k messages?

Comment: its server is located on windows and i havent checked its resources.
i wanted to compare the cpu usage stats of both rabbitMQ and redis pub/sub.  i want 100k messages.